# trouble trying to show an image from my static folder in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

im trying to show an image in my template if the profile haven't any picture. I have this code in my template

```
{% if not profileForm.avatar %}
   <img src="{% static 'img/empty-profile-picture.png' %}" alt="" />
{% endif %}
```

and i obtain that error

```
Template error:
In template /home/jaime/djcode/urgencias/templates/usuarios/profile_edit.html, error at line 68
   Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'elif', 'else' o 'endif'
```

Comment: `static`, not `satic` maybe...

Comment: sorry it was a mistake when i wrote here. The error is real.

Comment: Do you load the tag at the top of your template? `{% load static %}` or `{% load staticfiles %}`?

Comment: yes, my template extends from other named index.htm and i have the tag in the index

Comment: i solved by putting {% load staticfiles %} in the child template too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting the missing `{% load staticfiles %}` in the beginning of the child template too.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo - the keyword is `static`, not `satic`.

Comment: Error during template rendering

In template /home/jaime/djcode/urgencias/templates/usuarios/profile_edit.html, error at line 68
Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'elif', 'else' o 'endif'